# How To Split Separate Strings in 2 Different Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns of pipe delimited data that I need to break out into rows but the columns must stay together.  Here's what my data looks like:

```
Plan Name:  ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL
Plan Type:  HMO|POS|HMO|PPO
```

I need to end up with 4 rows that look like this:

```
1 - ABC HMO
2 - DEF POS
3 - GHI HMO
4 - JKL PPO
```

I know how to separate each column individually using the STUFF function but how do I keep the first value from column 1 with the first value from column 2, etc?  Don't know where to start.  Appreciate any help!

p.s. - I am not on SQL Server 2016 so can't use STRING_SPLIT

Answer (score 1):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with t as (
      select *
      from (values ('ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL', 'HMO|POS|HMO|PPO')) v(plannames, plantypes)
      ),
      cte as (
       select convert(varchar(max), left(plannames, charindex('|', plannames + '|') - 1)) as planname,
              convert(varchar(max), left(plantypes, charindex('|', plantypes + '|') - 1)) as plantype,
              convert(varchar(max), stuff(plannames, 1, charindex('|', plannames + '|'), '')) as planname_rest,
              convert(varchar(max), stuff(plantypes, 1, charindex('|', plantypes + '|'), '')) as plantype_rest,
              1 as lev
       from t
       union all
       select convert(varchar(max), left(planname_rest, charindex('|', planname_rest + '|') - 1)) as planname,
              convert(varchar(max), left(plantype_rest, charindex('|', plantype_rest + '|') - 1)) as plantype,
              convert(varchar(max), stuff(planname_rest, 1, charindex('|', planname_rest + '|'), '')) as planname_rest,
              convert(varchar(max), stuff(plantype_rest, 1, charindex('|', plantype_rest + '|'), '')) as plantype_rest,
              lev + 1
       from cte
       where planname_rest <> ''
       )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b8bd8c0f1b083769d73632e7ce815979) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Will this work for rows that have different numbers of plans/types, not just 4?

Comment: I'm not sure this is returning the expected results in the first place.

Comment: The above worked, and I've used it with my real data now and I think it's working.  Lamu why don't you think it's returning the expected results?  Just want to make sure I'm not missing something.  Thanks.

Comment: Larnu* (it's `rn` not `m`) and the fiddle didn't appear to provide the correct results @shdavis.

Comment: I did have to change plannames in the 4th convert statement to plantypes and it worked fine.

Comment: @shdavis701 . . . It is all fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`delimitedsplit8k_lead`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/) you could do:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(3), itemnumber) + ' - ' + PN.item + ' ' + PT.item
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.delimitedsplit8k_lead(YT.PlanName,'|') PN
     CROSS APPLY dbo.delimitedsplit8k_lead(YT.PlanType,'|') PT
WHERE PN.ItemNumber = PT.ItemNumber;
```

This *assumes* PlanName and PlanType have the same number of elements.

Comment: They do have the same number of elements in every row.